# How do you select attributes by name in Orange

Tags: python, orange

I have this file with a lot of attributes I want to use only a few of the attributes. How can I select for example three attributes with specific names?

The documentation only talks about random sampling of attributes and list indexing of the attributes that you want.

```
list_of_attr=[Orange.data.variable.ContinuousVariable(name="home_ppg_pre_game")]
new_domain = Orange.data.Domain(list_of_attr,
                                data.domain.class_var)
new_data = Orange.data.Table(new_domain, data)
```

I tried this but the new_data only had missing values.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `from_table` function:

```
list_of_attr=[Orange.data.variable.ContinuousVariable(name="home_ppg_pre_game")]
new_domain = Orange.data.Domain(list_of_attr,
                            data.domain.class_var)
new_data = Orange.data.Table.from_table(new_domain, data)
```

`from_table` creates a new table from selected columns and/or rows of an existing one. The columns are chosen using a domain.